# Photo extension memory constraints in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios-extensions

Per this question: [How to handle memory constraints in iOS 8 Photo Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405876/how-to-handle-memory-constraints-in-ios-8-photo-extensions) when iOS 8 was released, there was a significant memory constraint for photo extension developers that limited the available memory for the extension to roughly 100MB.

GPUImage, for example, can demand anywhere from 40MB to 100MB per edit. When the entire extension itself was only allocated roughly 100MB, this would cause the extension to crash.

Do these memory constraints still exist today in iOS 10 and on newer devices (iPhone 6S, iPhone 7)? If so, are the workarounds noted in that question (build exclusively with CoreImage or Metal, or reduce the image dimensions) still the only ways to work around this limitation?

Comment: This isn't really a new question — "is this still the case" is better handled by commenting on the original Q&A, or even running the test code that the original question provides. (FWIW, I've added a bit that might prove helpful to the comments on the duplicate question's answer.)

Comment: I never know what the appropriate course of action is - sometimes I've been led to believe asking a new question is better than trying to revive an old, outdated one.